# Making my own air conditioning hoses

Tags: ac

I am brand new to this site and was hoping to get some a/c hose clamp info. I am installing an aftermarket a/c-heater in my classic car. The company (Coldmaster) says I can use their a/c worm gear clamps. They also give you brass ferrules. The crimping machines are too pricey for me. Any suggestions before I have a shop charge up the system when I'm finished. Obviously don't want leaks. I have been reading on this site that spring clamps might be better for uniform clamping.

```
                                              Thank you,
                                              snakeoilii
```

Comment: What sort of suggestions are you wanting?  If you follow the directions of the company that provides the components you shouldn't have a problem.

Comment: Are there not premade hoses available for those fittings? find what they are called and search online id be shocked if there isn't.

Comment: Thank you for the quick responses. I guess what I really need to know is if ear crush clamps or worm the clamps that were provided would be sufficient. Just trying to avoid leaks and doing it economically as possible. Pre-made hoses are costly  and I'm trying to avoid putting an entire fitting through the firewall.